# gtk2 deleted, not theme avaible

Tags: debian, command-history, gtk, mate-desktop, gtk2

I tried to install a now theme for my Debian 8 Mate. I installed `gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64.deb`. as there was missing dependances, I deleted but, I deleted too many packages and now I don't have any theme. I tried to install what I deleted but nothing can revert (gtk2-engines is already installed,[image: capture of apparences settings]).

This is the result of `cat /var/log/apt/history.log`.

```
Start-Date: 2017-03-30  21:25:02
Commandline: apt-get -f install
Upgrade: gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64 (0.90.3+git20100810-0ubuntu1, 0.98.1.1-5)
End-Date: 2017-03-30  21:25:03

Start-Date: 2017-03-30  21:25:38
Commandline: apt-get autoremove gtk2-engines-murrine
Remove: murrine-themes:amd64 (0.98.8), gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64 (0.98.1.1-5), mate-themes:amd64 (1.9.2-1), gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 (1.4.4-2)
End-Date: 2017-03-30  21:25:40

Start-Date: 2017-03-30  21:25:54
Commandline: apt-get autoremove gtk2-engines
Remove: dmz-cursor-theme:amd64 (0.4.4), gtk2-engines:amd64 (2.20.2-3)
End-Date: 2017-03-30  21:25:55

Start-Date: 2017-03-30  21:28:51
Commandline: apt-get install dmz-cursor-theme gtk2-engines
Install: dmz-cursor-theme:amd64 (0.4.4), gtk2-engines:amd64 (2.20.2-3)
End-Date: 2017-03-30  21:28:53

Start-Date: 2017-03-30  21:29:50
Commandline: apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine
Install: murrine-themes:amd64 (0.98.8, automatic), gtk2-engines-murrine:amd64 (0.98.1.1-5)
End-Date: 2017-03-30  21:29:59
```

After reinstalling mate-themes package, it works. There is just a little problem, icons are truncated, I don't remember if there was the same at the first installation of Debian Mate : [image: screen capture.]

Problem with icon fixed, I restarted the computer and now, all is normal !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the **--purge** flag. When you did `apt-get autoremove package` it only removed the package contents and left the config files. Try

`apt-get autoremove --purge <package>`

to remove all the files and then

`apt-get install --reinstall <package>`

for a clean installation of the package.

Comment: Thank for your response, even if I reinstall packages I deleted, the problem persists. There is no mean to install the theme package by default ? I lost all the basic theme installed with mate.

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the mate-themes also? In your log file it shows it was autoremove but I don't see where you reinstalled it with gtk2. Not saying it's the fix but it couldn't hurt to try. If you try to install other theme packs such as the gtk2-themes-lite (i think that's the name), do they appear in your settings?

Comment: I'm not real sure about icons. I want to say I've changed them before on my laptop but it's been awhile. I would guess that you will probably need to use something like gnome-tweak-tool or dconf-editor which will help you customize many aspects of your desktop.